# Asp.net Special Character in dropdownlist box giving error

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, special-characters

I am populating dropdown list box from data base. In datbase there are some special charter(Soft's, --manage etc) in data. When i am clicking on show button to view the record based on selected value it is giving the following error..

Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax  near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '.

Source Error:
Line 208:        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
Line 209:        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Line 210:        da.Fill(ds);
Line 211:        gvUsrEdit.DataSource = ds;
Line 212:        gvUsrEdit.DataBind();
```

Any help please.

Comment: post ur code for retrieving your data from db and also binding to the dropdown

Comment: Thanks, i will put both

Comment: i have posted both.

Comment: did u tried new idea which u mentioned in ur qst ?

Comment: yes i tried and it is showing results but i am not sure it the right way or not as i am new and learning asp.net.

Comment: yes its the right way which will prevent the `sql Injection`

Comment: thanks a lot for valuable help. I will definitely search reading material for sql injection. Thanks!

Comment: In `StackOverflow` you should update your question , but you posted it as answer , so please add it to ur question part only

Comment: Thanks Krishna, next time i will write it in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send the parameter like this

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string d1 = ddlEmpName.Text;
string d2 = ddlQuater.Text;
string d3 = ddlyear.Text;
string d4 = ddlKRA.Text;
string strquery = "select * from  btaprs2 where vEmpID=@d1 and vQuarter=@d2 and vyear1=@d3 and tKRA=@d4 and v10='Active' ";

if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
{
con.Close();
}
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", d1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", d2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", d3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", d4);     
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvUsrEdit.DataSource = ds;
gvUsrEdit.DataBind();
con.Close();
}
```

**You should always use parameters in your query - NEVER concatenate together your SQL statements .**

*SQL Injection*

> SQL injection is a code injection technique that exploits a security
>   vulnerability occurring in the database layer of an application. The
>   vulnerability is present when user input is either incorrectly
>   filtered for string literal escape characters embedded in SQL
>   statements or user input is not strongly typed and thereby
>   unexpectedly executed. It is an instance of a more general class of
>   vulnerabilities that can occur whenever one programming or scripting
>   language is embedded inside another. SQL injection attacks are also
>   known as SQL insertion attacks

Comment: Thanks Krishna, Great!

Answer (score 0):

```
//ON page Load Binding all 4 DDL   
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string ses1 = Session["s"].ToString();
if (!IsPostBack)
{
string str5 = "SELECT distinct v_UserID FROM tblUsrMain WHERE v_UserID= '" + ses1 + "'";
da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(str5, con);
dt1 = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);
ddlEmpName.DataSource = dt1;
ddlEmpName.DataTextField = "v_UserID";
ddlEmpName.DataValueField = "v_UserID";
ddlEmpName.DataBind();
}
}

//Current Code whcih is giving error

protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strquery = "select * from  btaprs2 where vEmpID='" + ddlEmpName.Text + "' and vQuarter='" + ddlQuater.Text + "' and vyear1='" + ddlyear.Text + "' and tKRA='" +         ddlKRA.Text + "' and v10='Active'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvUsrEdit.DataSource = ds;
gvUsrEdit.DataBind();
con.Close();
}


//New Code i am thinking about
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string d1 = ddlEmpName.Text;
string d2 = ddlQuater.Text;
string d3 = ddlyear.Text;
string d4 = ddlKRA.Text;
string strquery = "select * from  btaprs2 where vEmpID=@d1 and vQuarter=@d2 and vyear1=@d3 and tKRA=@d4 and v10='Active' ";

if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
{
con.Close();
}
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", d1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", d2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", d3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", d4);     
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvUsrEdit.DataSource = ds;
gvUsrEdit.DataBind();
con.Close();
}
```